# How to sort the files in a directory?

Tags: file, sorting, terminal, directory, command

I'm making a zip file, and things start like `jul-16` or `jun-11`. I'd like it to be roughly sorted by months and days. Is there a way (or utility) to sort the files in a directory, so something like `ls` will then give them in a certain order? I'd prefer for it to be in months and by days. It seems that naturally, it ends up alphabetically, but I would have thought it would be in order of insertion.

Comment: one idea could be to rename the things so they start yyyy-mm-dd, then you can sort normally